# ionic 3 - popToRoot not destroying page

Tags: ios, angular, typescript, ionic3

I am using ionic 3 and when I popToRoot() the current page still executes and does not gets destoryed.  I thought popToRoot() is suppose to destroy the current page as it goes to the root page?  Here is the code:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.menuCtrl.swipeEnable(false);
  this.navCtrl.swipeBackEnabled = false;
  this.loop();
}




  loop() {
        this.API.doGet(URL)
          .then((data) => {
             if (data == 'Yes') {
                  ...
           }   
            else {
              // Wait on timer and call again - 10 seconds
              this.Timeout = setTimeout(() => { this.onLoopTimeout() }, 10000);
            }

          })
      .catch((err) => {
          this.errorTimeout = setTimeout(() => { this.loop(); }, 3000);
      })
  }


  onLoopTimeout() {
    this.loop();
  }




notInRepair() {
    // Clear timers
    clearTimeout(this.Timeout);
    clearTimeout(this.errorTimeout);
    // Go back to home page
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(ServicesPage);
    this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
  }
```

Do you guys know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: By current page which page do you mean? "ServicesPage"? can you say where you have added this code?

Comment: @SurajRao Yes so the current page is RepairPage and I am trying to destroy the RepairPage and go to the ServicesPage.  This is called when the user clicks the decline button.  The problem is there is a setTimeout loop that calls another function that keeps executing after getting to the ServicesPage

Comment: Can you add the function to the question? and which lifecycle method are you setting it in?

Comment: @SurajRao i edited the above question to include the function.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you have some additional timeout functions set because of the recursive calls. Why not clear them in `loop()` function before creating a new one? or use rxjs options to retry the call(assuming this is an http request`?

Comment: @SurajRao if I cleared the timeouts in loop() then wouldn't the loop stop?  I want the loop to keep going until notInRepair() is called